# run macro multiple sheets with exclusions

Tags: vba, excel, row

I am trying to run this macro across multiple data sheets in my workbook but i cant get the code to run properly across the workbook.  If i run the macro on a single sheet it works fine but i am trying to run all sheets now and exclude "DATA" and "UPDATE" sheets and haven't had any luck the code is below if there are any suggestions as for how to run properly through all worksheets? Thanks

```
  Sub UpdatePrices()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, Ldate As String, DateRng As Range
  Set DateRng = Range("A3") 'date range is last date
     Ldate = DateRng.Value 'defines ldate as most recent date

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

'Inserts a new row with containing today's Date and exclude sheets
  If Ldate <> Date And ws.Name <> "DATA" Or ws.Name <> "UPDATE" Then
    DateRng.EntireRow.Insert
    DateRng.Offset(-1, 0) = "=TODAY()"
    Else 
    End If
    Next ws
    End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
Sub UpdatePrices()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Ldate As String, DateRng As Range
    Set DateRng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")    'date range is last date
    Ldate = DateRng.Value    'defines ldate as most recent date

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Select
        'Inserts a new row with containing today's Date and exclude sheets
        If Ldate <> Date And UCase(ws.Name) <> "DATA" And UCase(ws.Name) <> "UPDATE" Then
            ws.Rows(DateRng.Row).EntireRow.Insert
            ws.Cells(DateRng.Row, DateRng.Column).Offset(-1, 0) = "=TODAY()"
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```